# Selectize.js: onChange event triggered on load Page

Tags: events, triggers, selectize.js

In selectize, I wont call event, but is it don't working
jquery event Working,
Selectize event don't working
Help please.

```
<div><select id='select'>
<option value="0">Item 0</option>
<option value="1">Item 1</option>
<option value="2">Item 2</option>
```

```
$(function () {
$('select').on('change', function () {
    alert("Original input event: Change");
});
$('select').selectize({
    onChange: function () {
        alert("Selectize event: Change");
    }
});
// this triggers an the event
$('#select').trigger( "change" );
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/6zyums3d/9/

Comment: Selectize onChange event is working in the fiddle that you have attached. what exactly is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I need filling dynamic option in select after click checkbox but I do not know how to do it

Comment: If on change checkbox, next... called event change on 
$(select).selectize({
   onchange: function(value){
...... code......
}
})

it would solve my problem

Comment: It sounds like you need to set the value (and possibly add the option), not trigger onChange, unless i'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Senx, I Win ))))
http://jsfiddle.net/dsqwared/6zyums3d/13/

Answer (score 6):

```
$('select').selectize({
    onInitialize: function() {
        this.trigger('change', this.getValue(), true);
    },
    onChange: function(value, isOnInitialize) {
        alert('Selectize changed: ' + value);
    }
});
```

Make sure that you passed `value` parameter to the `change` callback. Otehrwise it would be `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me with respect to triggering a `change` event on the select element itself.

```
$('select').selectize({
   onChange: function() {
     this.$input[0].dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger the event like this:

```
$('#select')[0].selectize.trigger( "change" );
```

Comment: You should pass `value` parameter. Your example will trigger `change` callback, but with `value = undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Trigger like this,

```
$('#select').selectize({
    onChange: function () {
        alert("Selectize event: Change");
    }
});
// this triggers an the event
$('#select').trigger( "change" );
```